# Class 'PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\Exception' not found

Tags: php, phpmailer

Using  PHP Mailer Version 6.0.6

I know similar questions are answered, but my situation is different.
I have successfully configured the script it was working perfectly fine; I was receiving mail, then all of a sudden without any changes from my side it started to throw me this error.

Error

```
    [Sun Nov 25 21:49:37.852920 2018] [:error] [pid 2060:tid 780] [client ::1:59300] 
   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\Exception' not found in   E:\\TCi\\htdocs\\sdresidency\\website\\plugins\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer.php:1920\nStack trace:\n#0  E:\\TCi\\htdocs\\sdresidency\\website\\plugins\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer.php(1774): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array)\n#1   E:\\TCi\\htdocs\\sdresidency\\website\\plugins\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer.php(1516): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Sun, 25 N...', 'This is a multi...')\n#2 
E:\\TCi\\htdocs\\sdresidency\\website\\plugins\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer.php(1352): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->postSend()\n#3  
E:\\TCi\\htdocs\\sdresidency\\website\\newbooking.php(38): PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\PHPMailer->send()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in
```

This is the configruation which i use to send mail

```
require_once "plugins/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require_once "plugins/PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
        $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP



    //Enable SMTP debugging. 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only                             
    //Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP          
    //Set SMTP host name                          
    $mail->Host = "md-in-30.webhostbox.net";
    //Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
    //Provide username and password     
    $mail->Username = "<my mail id>";                 
    $mail->Password = "<my password>";                           
    //If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
    //Set TCP port to connect to 
    $mail->Port = 587;                                   

    $mail->From = "<my mail id>";
    $mail->FromName = "SD RESIDENCY";
    $mail->addAddress("<receive mail id>", "name");
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "NEW RESERVATION";
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = "No HTML Support";

    if(!$mail->send()) 
    {    $_SESSION['message'] = 'SOME ERROR OCCURED, PLEASE TRY AGAIN';} 
    else 
    {    
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'BOOKING COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY';
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);

    }
```

I am storing html formatted mail content in the $message variable. 
I have tried all the answered questions here in stack and in other sites but with no luck; Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: what is structure of your project ? where is PHPMailer.php ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you need to extract a [mcve], because your question is considered off-topic without that. In particular, it's impossible to reproduce how exactly your code is set up concerning the loaded libraries and the setup of the class loader, which is particularly bad since the error could be caused by it.

Comment: You can fix this by adding `require_once 'plugins/PHPMailer/Exception.php';`, however, as @gbar's answer says, you should use composer instead, as the docs suggest.

Comment: @NikolaPavlović location of PHPMailer.php is like this <projectfolder>/plugins/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I will try it.

Comment: @Synchro I have tried this 'require_once plugins/PHPMailer/Exception.php';  but it doesn't work

Comment: Define “doesn’t work”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Try to replace `require_once "plugins/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";`  to

`require_once "./plugins/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";`

2. Do not include a libs directly. Use composer for an autoloading

   1. Install Composer https://getcomposer.org/download/
   2. Install PHP Mailer via Composer. Type on console `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer` https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer
   3. Include Composer's autoloader in php file. `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`
   4. PROFIT. You can include and use PHP Mailer and other libs very easy

Comment: I have used composer and the issue got solved. A big thanks to everyone who supported here.